# Django many to many avoiding duplication

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting duplication in my path (many to many) table, and would like it only to contain unique items.

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, through='ImageUser')

class ImageUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But, I seem to be able to create more than one image with the same path. I would like one unique image path to point to multiple users without having duplicate images in the Image table.

```
u = User.objects.create(username='AndyApple')
i = Image(path='img/andyapple.jpg')
i.save()
ui = ImageUser(user=u, image=i)
ui.save()

u2 = User.objects.create(username='BettyBanana')
ui = ImageUser(user=u2, image=i)
```

This seems to create two rows in the images table for the same image. The docs suggest this should not happen [ManyToManyField.through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your code adds duplicates to `Image` and not to `ImageUser` (which is how many-to-many table works)?

```
--------------------     ---------------------------     ----------------------------
|       Users      |     |         ImageUser       |     |           Image          |
--------------------     ---------------------------     ----------------------------
| id |   username  |     | id | user_id | image_id |     | id |         path        |
-------------------- --< --------------------------- >-- ----------------------------
| 1  |  AndyApple  |     | 1  |    1    |     1    |     | 1  | 'img/andyapple.jpg' |
--------------------     ---------------------------     ----------------------------
| 2  | BettyBanana |     | 2  |    2    |     1    |
--------------------     ---------------------------
```

But anyway, the problem is not right here, if you want:

> "one unique image path to point to multiple users without having
>   duplicate images in the Image table."

then you have to define the field as `unique`, see code sample below. In this case if you will try to save the image with the pathy that is already in DB the exception will be raised. But note that in this case if two users upload different images, but with the same name, then the last uploaded image will be used for both users.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
```